# Skip 'N' rows and fetch all available

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, query-performance

I have a simple requirement i want to skip 'N' rows and fetch all avaialbe. I need this as a part of my stored procedure something like

```
 WHERE /*some condition*/   
 ORDER BY 
        /* some case statement */    
OFFSET @SkipRows ROWS FETCH NEXT @TakeRows ROWS ONLY
```

now my requirement is if @TakeRows is some value say -1 i wanted to fetch all rows. I am trying to avoid an extra call to calculate row count

Comment: i am using sqlserver2008r2 order by clause is dynamic for which i already have case statement i am more worried about skiping and fetching rows

Comment: Fetch/Offset is evil. http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: ya i had see this link earlier but not found any issue till now with current query

Comment: cant i put some if clause over there,i tried but it was giving compilation error

Comment: Depending on how many rows you want to skip, it might actually be at lot easier and faster to just select all rows into where you need to use it and there skip the rows; instead of doing it in the query.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: that probably will have performance impact in my case as i have large rows(~10 million) and taking small number (50) out of it

Comment: @AnshulNigam So you need 50 rows out of 10 million, and not as mentioned in another comment "skip 5 and take the rest"?
If you have 10 million rows and only need a small subset - then I think you'd be better off pre calculating things, so you don't have to do it query time and can simply query for specific rows

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: its like pagination kind of thing where user will select how many rows he wanted to see so pre-fetch wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM  x
WHERE rn BETWEEN @start AND @End
```

Here @start and @End are the rows which you want to fetch in between.

Comment: the query i posted is simplified version and it already have partioning i am more worried about skipping and fetching part

Comment: @AnshulNigam:- As I posted you just need to provide the value to the variable `@start` and `@end` i.e., the rows which you want to fetch. For example if you want to fetch rows from 5 to 10 then simply put it 5 and 10 respectively.

Comment: my requirement is skip say '5' rows and fetch all avaialbe based on some variable

Answer (score 0):

try something like,

```
WHERE /*some condition*/   
ORDER BY 
        /* some case statement */    
OFFSET @SkipRows ROWS FETCH NEXT ISNULL(NULLIF(@TakeRows,-1),999999) ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: with your solution i can only fetch next '999999'

Comment: you can adjust the number with a guess as per you data.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> WHERE /*some condition*/   
>  ORDER BY 
>         /* some case statement */    
> OFFSET @SkipRows ROWS FETCH NEXT @TakeRows ROWS ONLY
> ```

If `@SkipRows` is a variable and if you want to return **ALL** the rows should -1 be given...then just use a separate query.

```
IF @SkipRows <= 0
    THEN BEGIN
            SELECT  TOP (@TakeROws) *
            FROM    <table>
            WHERE   <predicate>  
            ORDER BY 
             /* some case statement */    
         END
    ELSE BEGIN
            SELECT  *
            FROM    <table>
            WHERE <predicate>
            ORDER BY /*some case statement*/
            OFFSET @SkipRows FETCH NEXT @TakeRows ONLY
         END
    END
```

Or use a CASE Statement, whatever works for you.